# In the Eternals movie, why did this character's presence not affect the Earth?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

Towards the end of the *Eternals* movie

> The Celestial Arishem the Judge travels to Earth and floats within hundreds of miles from the surface of the planet

As can be seen in the video below:

**How massive is this Celestial here and how does his presence not instantly ruin the Earth and the moon's planetary orbits?**

Comment: Space magic, I suppose?

Comment: By being powerful enough not to if they did not want to?  The Celestials can move planets without difficulty.  In the comics at least, very few things are more powerful than a Celestial.

Comment: It totally affected it! Look at those clouds! _It almost made it rain, in London._ This is a power inconceivable!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The physiology of a Celestial, essentially “space gods,” is not entirely known for certain.

[The Celestials usually appear as massive armor-clad humanoids of enormous size, with most of them standing two thousand feet (610 meters) in height and some even larger (Exitar stands over 20,000 feet high).](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials) What we typically see as a “Celestial,” however, is just their armor-clad form. This armor can be taken off. After the Dreaming Celestial took off his helmet, he revealed his glowing face —suggesting that Celestials form may be comprised or partially comprised of energy.

Even if they were formed completely of a dense mass, their godlike powers are likely such that they can exist without interfering in the planetary systems they have been sent to manipulate.

Comment: Great analysis. Just want to point out the earths diameter is just shy of 8,000 miles across ( that’s 42,240,000 feet ) and it looks like this celestials head alone is the size of the whole earth. Perhaps you’re using comic book measurements and not those in the MCU - but even 20,000 feet at your high end is several magnitudes smaller than this celestial in this movie.

Comment: "it looks like this celestials head alone is the size of the whole earth" — that might be a "these cows are small, these cows are far away" kind of situation. A better comparison might be the Celestial against the Eternals, which I think are visible  in front of the Celestial's hand, so I don't think the Celestial's head can be the size of earth.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yeah. I’m not saying the celestials head is definitively as large as the Earth is. Just that in some scenes it “looks” that way. A 20,000 foot tall robots head cannot look earth sized from several different camera angles and pans unless there’s intentional size deception. I just think it’s safe to say from what we see in this movie from his head to his feet Arishem is physically larger than the Earth which means he probably has a fairly strong gravitational pull on this Earth.

Comment: @devsandbox How much mass does a spacegod mass if a spacegod’s mass is energy?

Comment: @SillybutTrue Energy and matter are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @devsandbox True, but even if pure energy (photons) does have inertia (if forced into absorption), they don't exert a gravitational force. That's the tricky part of wave-matter-dualism.

Comment: My primary point isn’t so much whether energy exerts a gravitational force, but rather do spacegods? I’m not sure of any canonical much less authoritative sources on the physics of spacegods.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The main point of Einstein's discovery of Mass Energy equivalence is that energy will affect space-time (gravity) exactly the same as mass.  Though obviously photons tend to not stay confined. Since the curve of spacetime takes energy - that energy causes more curve too - which is where the differences in Newton vs Einstein planet orbit predictions come from.

Comment: Perhaps Celestials are not necessarily "present" or "located" in spacetime the same way as ordinary mortals are. "Manifesting" themselves in a particular place wouldn't have the same effect.

Comment: We don't know if the Celestial was physically present near Earth, it may simply have appeared to humans in a similar way he magically appeared to Cerci several times during the movie. The only physical presence of a Celestial in the MCU we can take for granted is the asteroid-sized Celestial head that is inhabited by the Collector.

Answer (score 3):

I think that OP is implying from the provided tumbnail that Arishem is bigger than the Earth.  Honestly, I don't see anything in this sequence that really shows how big Arishem is.

This [link](https://screenrant.com/eternals-celestial-tiamut-size-300-miles-details/) states that VFX Supervisor Matt Aiken says Tiamut is 300 miles (~500km) tall.

[image]

This is just really not that big compared to the Earth.   If we assume that Tiamut and Arishem are similar is size, then the shot OP provides is just a matter of [forced perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_perspective).

**TLDR**:   Arishem just isn't that big compared to the Earth.   Why should it have much effect?