# Why didn’t the Celestial Arishem destroy the Deviants himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

In The Eternals movie there’s a scene where Arishem the Celestial explains the true purpose of the Eternals and the Deviants to Sersi:

> He explains that the Deviants were created to destroy apex predators ( such as the Dinosaurs ) that would otherwise wipe out humanity - however the Eternals were created to destroy the Deviants after they strayed from this purpose and started hunting humans instead of their predators.

**Why couldn’t/didn’t a being like Arishem the Celestial directly destroy the Deviants instead of creating the Eternals to do it for him if ( as it’s strongly implied in the film ) he could easily destroy the Deviants himself?**

Comment: Forget about that, why couldn't Arishem deal with the dinosaurs himself??

Comment: Perhaps he was busy with other stuff?

Comment: I believe someone in the film at one point says Arishem “lost control” of the Deviants, so presumably he couldn’t destroy the, easily or otherwise. Maybe he learned from that, and when making the Eternals added a handy failsafe that allowed him to float them all up into space when required.

Comment: To re-use an MCU metaphor, the boot doesn’t faff around destroying every last ant — it walks its human to the store and buys some ant powder.

Comment: There was an old lady who swallowed a fly...

Comment: OP here but the more I think about it the more I think the answer has to do with the Eternals always having a two-fold purpose to begin with: **1 )** Destroy the Deviants because of their evolutionary “flaws” and **2 )** Help humanity advance to support sustained population growth until Tiamut has enough energy to Emerge. Throughout the movie we see several instances of the Eternals ( primarily Phastos ) nudging humanity along on a path that will lead to their better societal development. If Arishem never created the Deviants or the Eternals who would/could guide humanity to develop at all?

Comment: It is because there are possibly millions of Deviants across the cosmos. Arishem can't deal with them all so he created the Eternals. Also, Eternals have another purpose which is to ensure that the Emergence happens. So, Arishem is hitting two targets with one arrow. You can think it as an automated process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Instead of trying to unscrew a screw with his bare fingers he built a screwdriver

Arishem created ants ( *deviants* ) that he later wants to exterminate from his property. Instead of setting it ablaze or filling the floors with billions of rounds of gunfire to destroy them ( *crushing the whole planet with brute force* ) he instead created his own Pest Control Company to take care of the ants for him while producing the least amount of collateral damage to the rest of the property possible.

MCU Celestials aren’t reality-warpers that can snap away all the “ants” but leave the butterfly’s unharmed ( *humans* ). They don’t have the infinity gauntlet - which is why later Arishem learned to build in a fail safe for the Eternals that allows them to be pulled from the earth at once and rallied up unto the celestial who called them. Such a method wasn’t built into the deviants.

But make no mistake, Arishem could destroy the whole Earth in the blink of an eye. He just can’t target and destroy the many deviants ( *or the dinosaurs originally* ) without having to first create a tool to extend his abilities. Like we humans do when our innate abilities don’t suffice.

Even space gods don’t try to unscrew screws with their bare fingers.

Answer (score 2):

### Because it is impractical for Arishem to do this

Arishem is an enormous Celestial being. His direct presence near any planet is hugely disruptive. His intention, as you have stated, is to promote the presence of intelligent life on planets such as Earth. If Arishem attempted to purge a planet of Deviants directly, collateral damage would be a certainty.

The Deviants are not like the Eternals, who are specifically designed so that Arishem can communicate with and (if necessary) recall them. Deviants are organic and would have to be destroyed directly.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256024/in-the-eternals-movie-why-did-this-characters-presence-not-affect-the-earth?rq=1
In this question the celestial’s gravitational fields are addressed. It appears that MCU celestials ( in addition to creating mini black holes ) can control their affect or lack thereof on planets they are in direct proximity of. Their presence isn’t disruptive to the nearby planets if they choose it not to be - as seen at the end of the movie. 
Otherwise though, it may be correct that there is no means for a celestial to target the deviants without collateral dmg

Comment: @devsandbox However, the sight of the enormous Arishem abducting people from the Earth would certainly qualify as 'disruptive'. Clearly it takes a major incident (such as the thwarting of Tiamat's *emergence*) for a Celestial to make an in-person visit to a planet.

Comment: EleventhDoctor You may be correct that if there was some way for Arishem to show up to Earth and start zapping Deviants he may not have chosen to for worry of making a scene and altering the course of humanity. That’s possible. Ultimately though I think the answer lies within his lack of ability to do that - like the later half of this answer suggests. Arishem couldn’t show up to zap away the Dinosaurs or the Deviants without harming the Earth and Humans inhabiting it in a catastrophic way. We don’t see MCU celestials zapping away such small beings like this anywhere. They can’t  do “anything”