# Why wasn’t the Earth destroyed in Eternals?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021, eternals

Eternals VFX supervisor Matt Aitken from Weta Digital stated that Tiamut is [*"about 300 miles, from his head to his toes"*](https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/eternals-vfx-interview-how-big-are-celestials-arishem-tiamut-revealed/) across. In the film we learn from Arishem The Judge that Celestials are born from seeds planted inside a planets core that gestate until the population reaches critical mass - causing the celestial to emerge. Note that the emergence completely destroys the planet in the process.

At the end of the movie

> the Uni-Mind is activated and Sersi takes on the combined powers of the other Eternals as Tiamut begins to emerge from the Earth. With her powers, Sersi freezes Tiamut and causes it to remain as some kind of marble statue.

Over the course of it's Emergence, Tiamuts head and hand would displace hundreds of miles of mantle rock from the Earths core which a 300 mile long object of such size moving from the core of the Earth to the surface would almost certainly cause massive explosions of rock elsewhere on the planet and continent sized sink holes in other areas. Such a disruption would likely destabilize the magnetic charge of the planet, throw it off it's gravitational axis and cause the whole planet to eventually break apart.

**Is there an in-movie explanation for why Earth holds up so well despite such a massive object moving such a great distance through the planet in such a short amount of time?**

Comment: [Because it's _Earth_, man!](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/abtvp/gahan_wilsons_movie_plot_generator_flow_chart/)

Comment: The Emergence is a two-part process: 1. New Celestial is 'born' and rises from the core of the Earth (causing major disruptions but not total annihilation); 2. New Celestial 'devours' Earth's consciousnesses (thereby, killing all intelligent life).

Comment: Look at Arishem's appearance. [It did nothing to affect Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/256024/21267). The destruction seems to be a deliberate action taken by a Celestial.

Comment: Gonna chalk this one up to Giant Space Baby Magic.

Answer (score 5):

**We don't know anything about the earth's core**

In the real world, we have a *fairly* good idea of how the earth's core/mantle work.  But if Earth's been seeded with a 300-mile-long god-baby... we've obviously missed something.

The movie itself doesn't explicitly state why none of the disastrous byproducts of Tiamut's partial emergence you describe occur.  However it's not a big logical leap to assume that everything we know about plate tectonics and the inner workings of Earth is simply **wrong**.  We've only had the one planet to study, and we've been studying everything and creating theories *as if there wasn't a 300-mile-long god in the middle of the planet*.  For all we know the baby Celestial is the entire reason earth has plate tectonics at all.  Or perhaps the core/mantle of earth is held stable (as much as it is) during the birth via Tiamut's innate celestial abilities, and by the time it is frozen in place it simply isn't displacing the mantle at a rate that would cause widespread damage.  Basically what it boils down to is your estimation of what would happen being based on the planet-as-we-think-it-is, which simply isn't the case for the movie because who knows what gets done to a planet internally to allow the growth of a Celestial within it.

Comment: I don't think it's the (lack of) knowledge of the core that is the issue.  Instead it's the sudden creation of a 300 mile high rock (well, solidified celestial actually) at the surface of the Earth and what that additional mass would do to the stability of the planet (due to the added rotational inertia)

Comment: @PeterM is it additional mass, if it was already inside the earth?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite From what we know of celestials they appear to be beings of pure energy, so their "mass" is unknowable.  However even if you consider that the mass of Tiamut was the same both before and after being solidified there still exists the issue of [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum).  Moving a large mass to the surface would at the very least affect the rotational speed of the Earth.  And attempting to do so in a very small period of time (compared to geological ages) will impact a lot of stress on the planet.

Comment: @PeterM: "From what we know of celestials they appear to be beings of pure energy" — do they? There was that cool space mining colony inside a dead one's apparently-matter-based head in _Guardians of the Galaxy_.

Comment: Even if we fully accepted your answer and assume the Earth’s  core works differently from ours due to Tiamut being encased in our core for 4+ billion years - the universal laws of physics itself are consistently shown to be the same in the MCU to our own real world reality unless otherwise altered by a specific extraordinary circumstance. Tiamut’s presence inside Earth doesn’t universally change gravity - and the universal law of gravity alone is the reason Earth wouldn’t survive this. The only part of your answer that sounds plausible is Tiamut choosing to protect Earth before he gets frozen.

Comment: So this has nothing to do with how Earths core and mantle work and everything to do with how Gravity works

Comment: @devsandbox have we been watching the same movies? These "specific extraordinary circumstances" are so common you can't move without tripping over one.

Comment: @OrangeDog what MCU movie gives a  “specific extraordinary circumstance” for all of Earth’s  gravity not obeying the laws of physics?

Comment: @devsandbox that's not what you claimed. Every MCU movie I can think of disobeys the "universal laws of physics" in some way.

Comment: @OrangeDog Read my first comment all the way to the end: *“Tiamut’s presence inside earth doesn’t universally change gravity”* like the OP was claiming for the same reason Hawkeye doesn’t just take off flying around like neo from the matrix in his show (spoiler alert). The MCU like most fiction tries to explain the supernatural with *in-story plot points*. It’s not random nonsense where science and physics make 0 sense. **There’s no plausible in-universe reason why the Earths core should cause gravity to work differently in this movie**

Comment: What I'm hearing is that we need to take a close look at [how gravity works in the Indian Ocean](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/jun/28/why-is-the-earths-gravity-weakest-in-an-area-of-the-indian-ocean).